# Get ProductName using Collection Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I've a list of product Ids and based on that product Id I want to get product Name but as the catalog_product_entity table doesn't contain the product name only sku, I'm trapped.

kindly check my code, I've tried left and right join both but not getting the name

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->getSelect()->joinRight( 
        array('table_alias'=>'my_table'), 
        'entity_id = table_alias.product_id',
        array('table_alias.*')
    );

$result = null;

foreach ($collection as $temp) {    
    $result[] = array(
        'name' => $temp->getCustomer_name(),               
    );
}
```

Comment: if you want to get product name and you have product id so just load the product using product id and you get all product information

Comment: well let say I've 100 products I'll run 100 queries to get product name for each product, that's not a good way to run a query on for each product Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved it

```
$resource        = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $readResource    = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
                $tableName       = $resource->getTableName('myTable');

                $results = $readResource->select('table_alias.*')
                ->from($tableName)
                ->joinLeft(
                                array('table_alias'=>'catalog_product_flat_1'), 
                                'product_id = table_alias.entity_id',
                                array('table_alias.*')
                            )->where('customer_id=?',$customerId);

                $products=$readResource->fetchAll($results);

                $dataList = array();

                foreach($products as $row)
                {
                    $dataList[] = array('productName'=>$row['name'],'price'=> $row['price'],'status'=>$row['status'],'myTable_id'=>$row['myTable_id']);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your collection to load the product name, then the first part of your code is right. Here's a simplified version:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

$result = array();

foreach ($collection as $temp) {
    $result[] = array('name' => $temp->getName());
}
```

Comment: sorry but I need the product Name acc to my_table, u missed the join

Comment: It is unclear to me why you are joining an external table to get the product name. I am guessing it's not the default product name attribute provided by Magento but something else you have customized, am I right?

Also in your code you are accessing an attribute called customer name, and not the actual product name. Feels that there is some information missing

Comment: No, actually I've saved the productId and customerId in myTable and now I want to show names of those productIds saved in the myTable so I'm joining it with catalog/product table